# underdamped oscillation with quadratic decay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I know that for a [2nd order linear differential equation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping), there are 3 possible scenarios: over-damped, critically damped and underdamped. For the underdamped case the solutions are of the form:
$e^{-\alpha t}(Acos(\omega_d t) + Bsin(\omega_d t))$

I am interested in a solution of the form $e^{-\alpha t^2}Acos(\omega_d t)$
i.e., I want the oscillations to die at quadratic rate.

Is there a corresponding differential equation that can generate this kind of behavior?

Comment: Since you know the answer, can't you just take derivatives and see what equations they satisfy? There must be at least 1 of each order.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll thanks for your prompt response. I am a machine learning person, and this showed up in some work related to kernel regression. My ODEs are a little rusty, but if I understood your point correctly taking the derivatives you will get terms like $te^{-\alpha t^2}cos$ and $e^{-\alpha t^2}sin$ etc. I remember multiplicative $t$ was popping due to repeating roots of characteristic equation. 
Also I assume the differential equations need to be nonlinear right? As if they were linear (and 2nd order) they would have resulted in classic linear decay damped oscillation.

Comment: Yes those are the terms you will generate, but there wont be any notion of characteristic equation here, nor does the equation need to be non-linear. You are probably remembering your diff. eq. where they only really covered equations with constant coefficients in detail. Constant coefficients are when characteristic equations and ordinary damped oscillation show up. 

The equations generated by just taking derivatives and then seeing how they compare to the original function can be made to be linear, but they will have non-constant coefficients. That is, the coefficients depend on t.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll thanks for the answer. You are right, linear time-varying systems should do the job here. I guess I was just expecting a more physically relevant system (i.e. some sort of nonlinear damping etc)

Comment: Ya such a thing might also be true. There are many many equations you could generate that have the same solution. These Gaussian functions do show up as solutions to the quantum harmonic oscillator (except their multiplied by Hermite polynomials, not oscillatory functions). You might be able to start with the QHO equation and modify it a bit to generate these oscillatory solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 scenarios of oscillation that you mentioned only show up for 2nd order linear differential equations with constant coefficients. Second order linear differential equations with non-constant coefficients can have a much broader variety of solutions.

As an example of my comment, if we take the derivative of your proposed solution, we get:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Big( e^{-\alpha t^2} A \cos{\omega_d t}  \Big) = -A e^{-\alpha t^2} (2 \alpha t \cos{\omega_d t} + \omega_d \sin{\omega_d t}) = A e^{-\alpha t^2}\cos{\omega_d t}(2 \alpha t + \omega_d \tan{\omega_d t})
$$

So, your function is a solution to the first order linear differential equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(t) = (2\alpha t+\omega_d \tan{\omega_d t}) f(t)
$$
Subject to any initial condition that you like to determine the coeficient $A$. We could do a similar thing to find a 2nd, 3rd, etc. order equation.